# UEFI-File System Not Found

Tags: uefi, dell-xps

I have a Dell XPS 13 laptop running Fedora 24.  It's currently running legacy boot, and I need to enable UEFI. When I select UEFI in the BIOS and try to add a boot option, I get this message:
File System Not Found!

I suspect the problem stems from the original OS install, and I'm really hoping to avoid a full reinstall.

Any suggestions?